# Open My Computer Properties in C# Windows App

Tags: c#, windows

Is there a way to open My Computer Properties from C# Windows Application?

For example, user click on a button "Computer Name" and it launches My Computer Properties - "Computer Name" Tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Process.Start("sysdm.cpl");`

Comment: Wow, sweet.  It even works if you do Start, Run and type in sysdm.cpl

Comment: I missed the user wanting to open "Computer Name"....   to do this, use Process.Start("control.exe", "sysdm.cpl,,1");

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Can you please tell us the syntax of the second parameter where you put "sysdm.cpl,,1"?

Comment: That is just the parameters to 'control.exe' (the first parameter to Process.Start is the program to run).  You can achieve the same thing by typing "control sysadm.cpl,,1" from Start/Run or from a command prompt as Robert says.

Comment: ...And if you mean the specific format of how I knew to use that particular paramters, check out the web page in my previous comments.

Answer (score 6):

Now that we know how to do that, here's a link to all of the other Control Panel files:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149648

```
File name      Purpose
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Access.cpl     Accessibility properties
Appwiz.cpl     Add/Remove Programs properties
Desk.cpl       Display properties
FindFast.cpl   FindFast (included with Microsoft Office for Windows 95)
Inetcpl.cpl    Internet properties
Intl.cpl       Regional Settings properties
Joy.cpl        Joystick properties
Main.cpl       Mouse, Fonts, Keyboard, and Printers properties
Mlcfg32.cpl    Microsoft Exchange or Windows Messaging properties
Mmsys.cpl      Multimedia properties
Modem.cpl      Modem properties
Netcpl.cpl     Network properties
Odbccp32.cpl   Data Sources (32-bit ODBC, included w/ Microsoft Office)
Password.cpl   Password properties
Sticpl.cpl     Scanners and Cameras properties
Sysdm.cpl      System properties and Add New Hardware wizard
Themes.cpl     Desktop Themes 
TimeDate.cpl   Date/Time properties
Wgpocpl.cpl    Microsoft Mail Post Office
```

Comment: Here's the page that I keep handy: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/control.htm